# How Can I convert this PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

```
<?php

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url)

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;

}

function getStories() {

    echo "<div id=\"stories\">";

    api_key = "ue5gpNuOXmVwacpftV5uEmjyTFwYmM4i";

    url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=".api_key;

}

$data = json_decode(CallAPI('GET', $url));

$num_results = $data -> num_results;

$output = '';

$title = '';

$story_url = '';

$byLine = '';

$section = '';

$abstract = '';

$height = '';

$width = '';

$img_url = '';

$caption = '';

$shortdate = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {

    if (is_array($data -> results[$i] -> multimedia)) {

        $height = $data -> results[$i] -> multimedia[1] -> height;

        $width = $data -> results[$i] -> multimedia[1] -> width;

        $img_url = $data -> results[$i] -> multimedia[1] -> url;

        $caption = $data -> results[$i] -> multimedia[1] -> caption;

        $date = date_create($data -> results[$i] -> multimedia[1] -> created_date);

        $shortdate = date_format($date, "F j, Y, g:i a");

        $image = "<img class=\"storypic\" src=\"".$img_url. '" alt="'.$caption. '" height="'.$height. '" width="'.$width. "\"/>";

    } else {

        $image = "<img class=\"storypic\" src=\"https://placehold.it" height =\"75\" width=\"75\" alt=\"Placeholder image\"/>";

    }

    $output.= '<div class="story">';

    $title = $data -> results[$i] -> title;

    $story_url = $data -> results[$i] -> url;

    $byLine = $data -> results[$i] -> byLine;

    $section = $data -> results[$i] -> section;

    $abstract = $data -> results[$i] -> abstract;

    $output.= '<div class="headline><a href"'.$story_url. '">'.$title. "<a/></div>".$image. "<div>".$byLine. "</div><div>".$shortdate "\"/>"
}
echo $output. "</div>";

}
```

This is PHP Script! Could anyone help me convert this code to JavaScript? I don't know about Javascript, but my project required JavaScript code! I'm feeling down now.  How can I do that? Could anyone help me? Thank you for your help!
Just need simple, basic JavaScript! I appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you tell us what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: This code will display information from API

Comment: Are you sure you want JavaScript code with API_key?

Comment: display it in square, including information title,by who,what section,etc

Comment: In javascript in order to fetch data from an api you can use fetch, you can learn a lot about it in this post https://javascript.info/fetch, we do not have access to the api result, in your question you need to handle this api results so if you could provide an example of the result we could present you a solution much closer to the expected result

Comment: hi Andreas! Yes

Comment: Ok. You do understand that your API key can/will be abused and your service will be locked out? @user615274 the PHP code kind of shows how the array is structured.

Comment: @Andreas makes an important observation, if you add an API_KEY in javascript anyone will be able to see it and use it, if you want to continue using javascript you could probably use lambda functions, services like netlify or frameworks like nextjs make this quite simple

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow where `$url` is coming from and what's the point of `getStories()`

Clearly there are better javascript-fu folks out there but this is my try!

```js
function callAPI(method, url, data = false) {
  return fetch(url, {
    method
  })
}

function getStories() {
  const api_key = "ue5gpNuOXmVwacpftV5uEmjyTFwYmM4i";
  const url = `http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=${api_key}`;

}

(async() => {

  const url = ''
  const data = await callAPI('GET', url).then(response => response.json());

  let output = ''

  for (let item of data.results) {
    let image = '';

    if (Array.isArray(item.multimedia)) {
      const [firstMultimedia] = item.multimedia;
      const {
        height,
        width,
        url: img_url,
        caption,
        created_date
      } = firstMultimedia;
      
      const date = new Date(created_date);
      const shortdate = date.toDateString(); // for more sophisticated formatting use 3rd party
    
      image = `<img class="storypic" src="${img_url}" alt="${caption}" height="${height}" width="${width}"\"/>`;

      continue;
    } else {
      image = `<img class="storypic" src="https://placehold.it" height ="75" width="75" alt="Placeholder image"/>`;
    }

    const {
      title,
      url: story_url,
      byLine,
      section,
      abstract
    } = item

    output = output + `<div class="story">
    <div class="headline>
      <a href"${story_url}">${title}<a/>
      </div>${image}<div>
      ${byLine}
    </div>
  <div>${shortdate}\"/>
  </div>`

  }

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript instead of CURL you can use [fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch) in order to get data from an API, also you can create [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create you html tags with content. Finally just use the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) method to merge your string template in the body of an html file in this example in the body of the #root div. Please take a look to this example

```js
const baseurl = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/";
const API_KEY = "ue5gpNuOXmVwacpftV5uEmjyTFwYmM4i";

async function fetchNews(section = "home") {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseurl}${section}.json?api-key=${API_KEY}`);

  return await response.json();
}

function render() {
  fetchNews().then((news) => {
    const { num_results, results } = news;
    const output = results
      .map((entry) => {
        const { height, width, url, caption } = entry.multimedia[1];
        const image = `<img class="storypic" src="${url}" alt="${caption}" height="${height}" width="${width}"/>`;

        return `<div class="story">
            <div class="headline">
                <a href="${entry.url}">${entry.title}</a>
                <div>${entry.byline}</div>
                <div>${entry.created_date}</div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
      })
      .join("");

    document.querySelector("#root").innerHTML = output;
  });
}

render();
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```